# Jump to Firebase parent Nodes from Child Nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello all i have a my fire-base structure like this

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SzT1.png)

I have an array list inside an node in fire-base , I need to loop through this list and jump to each ID to get information i need like the database photo shows.

what I've tried so far

```js
public static void checkIfCurrentUserLiked(final HomeFragment.PostsViewHolder postsViewHolder, String postKey) {

        userID = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
        likesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("likes");
        postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(postKey);
        postsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("likes")) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("likes").getChildren()) {
                        likesRef.child(Objects.requireNonNull(ds.getValue()).toString())
                                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        Like like = snapshot.getValue(Like.class);
                                        if (like != null && like.getLikedUserID().equals(userID)) {
                                            postsViewHolder.likesImage.setImageResource
                                                    (R.drawable.ic_item_home_post_like_filled);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
                                });
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

i have no error , just nothing happens , data are not fetched as expected

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: actually no error , it just do nothing

Comment: can you add a log and tell me which data is getting retrieved

Comment: Have you tried to log the `databaseError`? Is it something printed out in the logcat? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @MustafaBahaa have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(postKey);
```

into this:

```
postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(postKey);
```

According to your database, you have node `posts` before the `postKey`, therefore you need to add it when referencing to a location.